# Error with functions

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I tried custom functions:

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
    AcceptInput = true;
    targetScript.enabled = false;
    changeSprite ();
}
function changeSprite () {
    //other stuff
}
```

It had an error:

```
Assets/Scripts/Button.js(70,1): BCE0070: Definition of 'Button.changeSprite()'
depends on 'Button.changeSprite()' whose type could not be resolved because of
a cycle. Explicitly declare the type of either one to break the cycle.
```

I don't get what's wrong with the function. can any body help me?

Comment: I think this error is related to coroutines. See this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/48199/definition-of-scriptfunction-depends-on-scriptfunc.html

Answer (score 1):

As the error message tells us, you can try defining the return type of the function, in this case "void";

```
    function changeSprite(): void {
        //other stuff
    }
```

Comment: I did the thing you told me to and gave me this error:Assets/Scripts/Buttons.js(43,27): BCE0101: Return type 'void' cannot be used on a generator. Did you mean 'IEnumerator'? You can also use 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' or 'object'.

Comment: could you post the whole script? I suspect there is something outside of the code you posted that is causing the problems.